# My eclipse can't find jar's

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to work with Excel in my project, so I added few additional jar's to it:

MyBuildPath

[image]

When I'm trying to run my project, I'm getting such exceptions:

---

```
:compileJavaC:\Users\Azimut\Documents\workspaces\helperandroid\MultiViewProjectFXML\src\main\java\myClasses\SearchOrders.java:12: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
^
C:\Users\Azimut\Documents\workspaces\helperandroid\MultiViewProjectFXML\src\main\java\myClasses\SearchOrders.java:13: error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

.......

```
C:\Users\Azimut\Documents\workspaces\helperandroid\MultiViewProjectFXML\src\main\java\myClasses\SearchOrders.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
    public static String getCellText(Cell cell) {
                                     ^
      symbol:   class Cell
      location: class SearchOrders

    13 errors
     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED
```

---

I searched a lot through the internet, but I still can't understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are excuting your code commandline, and not using eclipse.
In that case, You will have to add dependency jars in class path when you run the code.
`java -cp <jar files>` is the possible way.

Are you able to execute in eclipse ?
Regards,
~KD

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with Gluon pluig. I tried to run my project without this "part" of code and all goes well. Also almost the same code with the same jar's worked well in other my project, but not with javafx and gluon.